# C# Blazor shared resource files error: The resource type GlobalResources does not have an accessible static property named

Tags: blazor-server-side, resx

I have a net6 project (V2.resources) where I've put my resource files in.

I have a Blazor server project in which I use the resources for localization. This works fine.
I also have a net6 Models project (V2.Models). This contains all my viewmodels where some of them have DataAnnotions to validate.

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredField", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(GlobalResources))]
        public string Name { get; set; }
```

The problem occures here. When the name field is invalid it throws the following error:

> The resource type 'V2.Resources.GlobalResources' does not have an
> accessible static property named 'RequiredField'

anyone has an idea where does this comes from? They are accessible from the Blazor project. The resource file is set to PublicResXFileCodeGenerator.

Project structure:

[image]

In Blazor project Program.cs

> ```
> builder.Services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it :)

The models project was missning nuget package:

> Microsoft.Extensions.Localization

Now it works as a charm.